# What does int 0x81 do exactly?

Tags: assembly, x86

Is int 0x81 in x86 assembly code assigning an integer to a register space, or just invoking an interrupt?

Comment: Jason, please post a code segment, so we can see the context of what you're talking about.

Comment: Why do you think that it might be "assigning an integer to a register space"?

Answer (score 7):

`INT n` where n is an integer literal is a software interrupt. The meaning of that interrupt number (and if it's even allowed) is operating system dependent.

Comment: So nothing to do with registers?

Comment: Nothing to do with registers...  Unless you consider the fact that CS:IP and SP will change?